# Invalid permission "user_posts" in react-native-fbsdk although it is approved by review

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Simple.
I've built a login flow that uses Facebook authentication for my app.

```
LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile", "email"])
```

this has no issues, and proceeds to log the user in.

If instead I put in:

```
LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_posts"])
```

it throws an error

```
Login fail with error: Error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349013 [message]: The app requested an invalid permission.
```

Permission is valid, and approved by app review. I can't seem to find a workaround or fix. [There is even an issue in react-native-fbsdk package](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/771)

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any solutions?

Comment: Update:
I've submitted a bug report to Facebook and apparently they've stopped supporting React Native SDK

More details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1208015186312456/)

The issue still stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while, but the solution is "simple" enough.

Instead of using `react-native-fbsdk` module you can switch to `expo-facebook` module.

Add `react-native-unimodules`. Documentation available [here](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/)

After that add `expo-facebook`. Documentation available [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/)